# Calculating averages considering two columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following data : [Snap from the data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sub8o.png)

I want to calculate the average NO2 for each elevation and month. The result should be a data frame with one column per elevation angle and one row per month.

I tried the following code:

```
azimuth_W.groupby([azimuth_W.index.month,'elevation_angle']).mean()
```

The result is now what I was exactly looking for, the `'elevation_angle'` are still rows, not columns. What can I do?

Many many thanks.

Comment: Use `azimuth_W.groupby([azimuth_W.index.month,'elevation_angle']).mean().reset_index()`

Comment: Not what i was looking for, now. As i said, the result should be a data frame with one column per elevation angle and one row per month.

Comment: Do you think `azimuth_W.groupby([azimuth_W.index.month,'elevation_angle']).mean().unstack()`

Comment: Yes, this is the form I am looking for. But I think I have some errors, as I want to have just the means for 'NO2_scd', excluding 'solar_zenith_angle'. Thanks

Comment: Do you think `azimuth_W.groupby([azimuth_W.index.month,'elevation_angle'])['NO2'].mean().unstack()` ?

Comment: Yes, it's getting there. Many many thanks. I have a lot of NaN values. If I don't run .unstack() they look normal and I don't have NaN values. Any ideas ?

Comment: It is normal, because some pairs colu, index is missing, so added nans.

Comment: Got it. Again, thank you, problem solved.